Firefox Websocket Connection to localhost not working
I have a simple website that should connect to a websocket via this code:
// Replace 'your_token_here' with your actual JWT token
const token =
    "myToken";

// URL encode the token to handle special characters correctly
const encodedToken = encodeURIComponent(token);

// WebSocket URL with the encoded token as a query parameter
const wsUrl = `wss://localhost:6000/?token=${encodedToken}`;

// Create a new WebSocket object
const websocket = new WebSocket(wsUrl);

// Event listener for successfully establishing a connection
websocket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log("WebSocket connection established:", event);
    // You can send messages to the server upon connection
    websocket.send("Hello Server!");
};

// Event listener for receiving messages from the server
websocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log("Message received from server:", event.data);
};

// Event listener for errors in the WebSocket connection
websocket.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error("WebSocket error observed:", event);
};

// Event listener for when the WebSocket connection is closed
websocket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log("WebSocket connection closed:", event);
    console.log("Close code:", event.code, "Reason:", event.reason);
};


The backend looks like this:
const WebSocket = require("ws");
const url = require("url");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const https = require("https");
const fs = require("fs");
require("dotenv").config({ path: ".env" });

const serverOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync("server.key"),
    cert: fs.readFileSync("server.cert"),
};

const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
    noServer: true,
});

let sockets = [];

wss.on("connection", function (socket) {
    sockets.push(socket);
    console.log(sockets.length);

    /**
     * Event listener for messages on the socket. When a message is received,
     * it is broadcasted to all connected sockets.
     *
     * @param {string} msg - The message received from the client.
     */
    socket.on("message", function (msg) {
        sockets.forEach((s) => s.send(msg));
    });

    /**
     * Event listener for the close event on the socket. Removes the closed socket
     * from the `sockets` array to keep the list of active sockets up to date.
     */
    socket.on("close", function () {
        sockets = sockets.filter((s) => s !== socket);
    });
});

const server = https.createServer(serverOptions, (req, res) => {
    // Set CORS headers
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.setHeader(
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
        "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
    );

    // Respond to OPTIONS preflight request
    if (req.method === "OPTIONS") {
        res.writeHead(204);
        res.end();
        return;
    }

    // Handle other requests here as needed
});

server.on("upgrade", (request, socket, head) => {
    console.log("upgrade request received");
    const { query } = url.parse(request.url, true);
    const token = query.token;

    try {
        /**
         * Verifies the provided JWT token using the secret key from the environment
         * variables. If verification fails, it throws an error.
         */
        jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);

        /**
         * Handles the WebSocket connection upgrade by passing the request, socket,
         * and head data to the WebSocket server.
         */
        wss.handleUpgrade(request, socket, head, (ws) => {
            wss.emit("connection", ws, request);
        });
    } catch (err) {
        /**
         * If token verification fails, respond with 401 Unauthorized and close the socket.
         */
        socket.write("HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized\r\n\r\n");
        socket.destroy();
        return;
    }
});

server.listen(6000, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log("Server listening on port 6000");
});


Connecting to my websocket from another backend service works like a charm but when I try connecting using the frontend code I always get an error 1006 (in Firefox) and the websocket connection isn't even shown in the networking tab of the dev tools. When I try using Edge I get the same error but at least the connection is (somewhat) shown in the networking tab but labeld as 'delayed: 22.4 days'

